# haproxy + nginx get client ip behind anonymous proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, haproxy, anonymous

I'm creating an application, where frontend is Haproxy and nginx.
Do you know a way to get client IP address if navigates behind anonymous proxy with HAproxy ?

My actual configuration for haproxy use "option forwardfor", but I get anonymous proxy IP instead real client IP in nginx logs (using $http_x_forwarded_for var)

```
frontend general_frontend
  bind 111.111.111.111:80
  default_backend nginx_farm_backend
backend nginx_farm_backend
  balance roundrobin
  option  abortonclose
  option  forwardfor

  http-check disable-on-404
  http-check expect string nginx
  option httpchk GET /index.html HTTP/1.0

  # - Nodes
  server  nginx-server-1 222.222.222.222:8080 check on-error mark-down observe layer7 error-limit 1
  server  nginx-server-1 333.333.333.333:8080 check on-error mark-down observe layer7 error-limit 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Not clear what you want. Anonymous proxies don't expose their client address'. It's their purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Do you Using $remote_addr var for nginx log format?